# Axiomatizing Solid Geometry

Tags: geometry

In Moise's elementary geometry book it postulates plane geometry very well for metric approach. But for solid geometry, it doesn't cover widely and I have some questions caused from this gap. Do we need to add to this system new postulates for solid geometry and if we need what could be the new postulates. And in the book, volume theory for solids isn't covered as area theory because volume theory requires Lebesgue measure. How can we postulate rigorously (like plane areas in the book) with Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Why would areas require less Lebesgue measuring than volumes?

Comment: I don't know this question's answer. The book, as I understood, can give the postulates  of area and prove this area function exists in framework of postulates it uses with Jordan measure. But when it comes to volume theory it can only give the postulates but can't prove a volume function exists with only Jordan measure and it says Jordan measure isn't enough. I can assume from this area can be developed with Lebesgue, too but to be simple Jordan is enough. But when it comes to volumes Jordan isn't enough. But as I said I don't know how to develop neither area nor volume with Lebesgue.